# C# .net Core and Oracle set encoding

Tags: c#, oracle, unicode, ado.net, .net-core

In web-api project on `.Net Core` has connect to `Oracle` DB via `dotNetCore.data.OracleClient (nugget package)`

I read data from pipelined funxction like this:

```
 using (DbConnection connection = new OracleConnection("oraclecs")) {
    connection.Open();

    using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

      cmd.CommandText = "select name from Table(SCHEMA.PACKAGE.FUNC(PARAM1=>1,PARAM2=>4))";

      DbDataReader er = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      while (er.Read()) {
        string Name = er.GetValue(er.GetOrdinal(name: "name")).ToString();
      }
      connection.Close();
    }
  }
```

Name in database in Russian language 
DB encoding `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is `CL8MSWIN1251`

When I got value from field `name` I see ???????? instead of real name

Also just `select` in command text via `Oracle SQL Developer` return correct data

What can help me to fix it?

Comment: Where is it that you are seeing the value? I expect whatever you are viewing the result in just isn't able to display those characters

Comment: What is the *field's* type? In any case, don't use ASCII fields (ie varchar), use Unicode fields (ie varchar2) so you don't have to worry about encodings

Comment: In db I use varchar2

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, `varchar` is identical to `varchar2`. I assume you mean `Nvarchar2` - however this will not solve the problem.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of dozens of other questions, unrelated to ASP.NET Core. Non-English text was stored in an ASCII field using the *wrong* codepage. When the application tried to read the data using the configured codepate the actual byte values were invalid for that codepage and had to be replaced by `?` or the similar looking Unicode Replacement Character �

Comment: musefan I return values. When I call my api via postman - I see ???. Also in debugging mode

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit you are right. Unicode will solve the actual problem. It can't recover lost data though. If the `?` characters were generated during insertion the data was lost from the beginning

Comment: @IgorCova doesn't matter. Worst case, the data is lost. Best case, you need to discover what the original encoding was and use it instead of `CL8MSWIN1251`. If you use another tool to read the data and still see `?` though, the data was lost when it was written.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos via Oracle SQL Developer I see correst name with russian lettres

Comment: @IgorCova you should use a Unicode field type like `nvarchar2`. When writing you should use parameterized queries, not concatenate string values. If you *have* to do so, use the `N` prefix. Ensure the parameter type is a Unicode type

Comment: What is your `NLS_LANG` value? It can be set as Environment variable or in Registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG`, resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` If it is not set the Oracle defaults it to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII` which does not support Russian language.

Comment: @IgorCova then you dodged a bullet. The data was written using the wrong codepage but not lost. You still have to fix the wrong field type if you want to avoid this in the future.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I use varchar2

Comment: @IgorCova for now you should try various codepages until you find the one that was actually used. I suspect it was Latin1, ie `AMERICAN_AMERICA`. You'll have to use this to convert the ASCII text to Unicode too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I think you are wrong. Oracle SQL Developer returns correct data, so data seems to be OK. It is just a matter of display in the client.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how can I do it?

Comment: @IgorCova `varchar2` is an ASCII type. The [Unicode type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch7progrunicode.htm) is `nvarchar2`. Somewhere, somehow the wrong encoding was used to write the data. To avoid similar problems in the future *don't* use ASCII.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit .NET strings are Unicode. Windows strings are Unicode. Vector fonts on Windows are also Unicode even when they don't contain glyphs for all languages. The most common fonts like Arial, Times New Roman, etc do contain Cyrillic characters. Varchar2 isn't Unicode though and will almost guarantee encoding problems

Comment: It *could* be a font that doesn't have the correct language, but that doesn't solve the underlying problem. The Arial, Times New Roman, Courier New, Verdana fonts do have the Cyrillic character set though.

Comment: All the same I did not understand how to solve My problem. 

The data is read correctly through Oracle SQL developer it means data writed correctly, but when I request data via web-api .net core data is crashed, mb there has a parameter in the connection setup to the database with the encoding specified?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, `VARCHAR2` uses the `NLS_CHARACTERSET` where nowadays default is `AL32UTF8`, i.e. Unicode. Here it is `CL8MSWIN1251` which is fine for Russian (and for sure not ASCII). Sorry for being impolite but in spite of your impressive reputation all your comments above are dross.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I can't check NLS_LANG value. I don't have access to server where database located. Maybe some settins my project or connection to Oracle can help me, do you know?

Comment: I don't mean the NLS_LANG on the server. What is it on your client - that's what counts.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit NLS_LANG in Oracle SQL Developer set to Russian

Comment: No, format of `NLS_LANG` is `language_territory.charset`. What is the exact value? Actually only the **charset** value is relevant. Since Oracle SQL Developer returns correct data, I don't care about any settings in there. What is set in your environment?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It in run in my Oracle SQL Dev
 LANGUAGE RUSSIAN
TERRITORY RUSSIA
CHARACTER SET CL8MSWIN1251

Comment: Again, your settings in Oracle SQL Developer does not matter at all! Go to your environment settings and set `NLS_LANG=.CL8MSWIN1251` (include the dot!) and run your .net application.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thank you! in my docker I've set NLS_LANG=.CL8MSWIN1251 and Yes -. Now it works correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help to [@wernfried-domscheit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit)

My .net Core web-api running in docker

I've set NLS_LANG=.CL8MSWIN1251 in file docker-compose.override.yml
And it helped to me

My docker-compose.override.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ORACLE_CS=Data Source = ip:port/sid;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=user; Password=password;
      - NLS_LANG=.CL8MSWIN1251
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```